# VBA mapping/transferring sentences in Word to columns in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to transfer info from the following format in Word to Excel columns "a", "b", "c", "d" while ignoring the number in front which is the index of the entry (21 in this case)

[image]

So far this is what I got but it's only for the bold text on the top left but I don't know how to get the other substrings. Any help with this will be appreciated.

```
Sub TheBoldAndTheExcelful()
  Dim docCur As Document
  Dim snt As Range
  Dim i As Integer
  'Requires a reference to the 'Microsoft Excel XX.0 Object Library'
  Dim appXL As Excel.Application, xlWB As Excel.Workbook, xlWS As Excel.Worksheet

  'This assumes excel is currently closed
  Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  appXL.Visible = True
  Set xlWB = appXL.Workbooks.Add
  Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets(1)

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set docCur = ActiveDocument

  For Each snt In docCur.Sentences
    If snt.Bold = True Then
      i = i + 1
      xlWS.Cells(i, 1).Value = snt.Text
    End If
  Next snt

ExitHandler:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set snt = Nothing
  Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
  Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example,

```
  For Each snt In docCur.Sentences
    If snt.Bold = True Then
      i = i + 1
      xlWS.Cells(i, 1).Value = snt.Text
    End If
  Next snt
```

Let's rewrite that first

```
  For Each snt In docCur.Sentences
    If snt.Bold = True Then
      i = i + 1
      xlWS.Cells(i, COLUMN_A).Value = snt.Text
    End If
  Next snt
```

You are only including the bold sentence (`If snt.Bold = True`), and writing to `COLUMN_A` alone.

What you *want* is the bold sentence *and* the three sentences that follow after it, and you want to write to *four* columns.

So change this section to:

```
'  Dim j As Long ' - make sure to have already declared this, or just uncomment this line

  For j = 1 to docCur.Sentences.Count ' perhaps docCur.Paragraphs instead?
    If docCur.Sentences(j).Bold = True Then
      i = i + 1
      ' used 1+n and j+n for ease of understanding, but you can make these constant with a real solution; or you could even put this in another loop if you wanted, e.g. For n = 0 to 3, ...
      xlWS.Cells(i, 1+0).Value = docCur.Sentences(j+0).Text
      xlWS.Cells(i, 1+1).Value = docCur.Sentences(j+1).Text
      xlWS.Cells(i, 1+2).Value = docCur.Sentences(j+2).Text
      xlWS.Cells(i, 1+3).Value = docCur.Sentences(j+3).Text
    End If
  Next j
```

Or, to maximise performance:

```
'  Dim j As Long ' - make sure to have already declared this, or just uncomment this line

  With docCur.Sentences ' perhaps docCur.Paragraphs instead?
    For j = 1 To .Count
      If .Item(j).Bold = True Then
        i = i + 1
        xlWS.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 4).Value = Array(.Item(j + 0).Text, .Item(j + 1).Text, .Item(j + 2).Text, .Item(j + 3).Text)
      End If
    Next j
  End With
```

Based on comments, changes:

1. **Problem**: "Also some sentences that I have go a little on the second line so technically there would be 5 sentences total since formatting. Any way to concatenate the two lines which actually should represent the same sentence?":
   **Solution**: Concatenate with `&`:
   **Example**:
   Fourth item of `Array(...)` changes
   from `.Item(j + 3).Text`
   to `.Item(j + 3).Text & .Item(j + 4).Text)`
2. **Problem**: "Instead when creating the last column, everything ends in some funny looking crosses (like an Egyptian Ankh). Any idea how to remove those?":
   **Solution**: Either remove the last character in the problem sentence using `Left(string, Len(string)-1)`, or use `Replace(string, [problem character], "")`
   **Example**:
   Problem item (presuming sentence 4) in `Array(...)` changes
   from `.Item(j + 3).Text`
   to `Left(.Item(j + 3).Text, Len(.Item(j + 3).Text) - 1)`

Updated:

```
'  Dim j As Long ' - make sure to have already declared this, or just uncomment this line

  With docCur.Sentences ' perhaps docCur.Paragraphs instead?
    For j = 1 To .Count
      If .Item(j).Bold = True Then
        i = i + 1
        xlWS.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 4).Value = Array(.Item(j + 0).Text, .Item(j + 1).Text, .Item(j + 2).Text, Left(.Item(j + 3).Text, Len(.Item(j + 3).Text) - 1) & .Item(j + 4).Text)
      End If
    Next j
  End With
```

If this isn't a complete fix, please provide a sample file.

Comment: Got an error: Application-defined or object defined error

Comment: Nevermind. Fixed this error. I get the 2010. Instead when creating the last column, everything ends in some funny looking crosses (like an Egyptian Ankh). Any idea how to remove those?

Comment: Also some sentences that I have go a little on the second line so technically there would be 5 sentences total since formatting. Any way to concatenate the two lines which actually should represent the same sentence?

Comment: I'll make an attempt at adapting it based on your description, but can you please provide a sample file?